# CSS Tooltip inside scrolling div

Tags: css

I have a simple CSS help popup that's been working well for me in most simple layouts. But now it needs to work inside a scrolling div.

Given the example HTML:

```
<div style="overflow:scroll; width:80px">
<a href="#" class="tooltip">
an image
<span>some hidden tooltip which is a bit longer in here</span>
</a>
</div>
```

(Note: in the real world there will be multiple things with tooltips inside the scrolling div)

I have the CSS:

```
a.tooltip span 
{
display:none;
position:absolute;
padding:0px 0px 2px 2px;
background:yellow; 
text-decoration:none;
vertical-align:top;
}

a.tooltip:hover span
{
display:inline; 
position:absolute;
padding:0px 0px 2px 2px;
top:0;
left:18px;
background:yellow; 
text-decoration:none;
vertical-align:top;
z-index:5;
}

a.tooltip 
{
border-width:0px; 
text-decoration:none;
}

a.tooltip:hover
{
border-width:0px; 
text-decoration:none;
position:relative;
}
```

Is it possible to have the popup pop out of the scrolling div so it's readable without causing the div to scroll?

Is this achievable in CSS alone, without using javascript?

edit: **[Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/5mASU/)** kindly provided by *Kyle Sevenoaks*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible, because z-indexes work from the parent, the child element won't be able to display the span over the top. This CSS tooltip just adds another element when the `<a>` is hovered. I think you might have to go the jQuery route.

Also, try to post [live examples](http://jsfiddle.net/5mASU/) of your problem instead of a long list of HTML and CSS, it's easier for us to help you :)

Comment: I had a sneaking suspicion that might be the case. Thanks for linking jsFiddle, I'll use that for examples in the future!

Comment: No problem, I use this tooltip all the time because it's just so simple, but when it comes to things like this I just go over to jQuery. There are loads of jQuery tooltips and most are really easy to implement.

Comment: yeah I've fortunately already integrated jQuery into this particular project for other things, so that may well be the way to go. Wanted to check though, as I always like to try and keep things as simple as possible :)

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `:hover` on the entire DIV. and place your span directly in the div. (This solution does not work in IE6 for example).

see a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/5mASU/1/

Or you could set i higher z-index to the tooltip and use position fixed, it works:
http://jsfiddle.net/5mASU/3/

also avoid resetting the same values in the hover here is a cleaned up version:
http://jsfiddle.net/5mASU/4/

if for example you set

```
a {
  padding: 5px; 
}
a:hover {
  // no need to reset the padding here
}
```

you don't need to reset the padding in the `:hover` the hover heritages the padding form the style set for the a. Just reset values you want to change between the normal and the hover status.

Comment: THis is a good solution if you want the tooltip to apply to the entire DIV, but it won't apply to selected words.

Comment: thanks for that, unfortunately in the real world I have more than one tooltip inside the scrolling div - I'll update the question to be clearer on this point.

Comment: yeah i know but it was the only solution in pure CSS i could think of if you want to use a jquery tooltip i recommend you this one: http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html

Comment: i have found a way to do it with pure css check my example (i have edited my post)

Comment: the fixed layout means that if there is more than one item in the scrollable div it will not be next to the item you mouseover. for example - http://jsfiddle.net/5mASU/5/ both tooltips appear in the same place, which is undesirable. Thanks for the tooltip link though, looks interesting!

Comment: you are welcome, ok then there is no pure CSS solution to this problem.